# Трехточечная перспективная проекция объекта OpenGL

Tags: opengl

Как правильно посчитать матрицу трехточечного преобразования, если даны координаты трех точек

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю как это будет выглядеть в OpenGL, но в общем случае, вам необходимо для результирующей матрицы трехточечной перспективной проекции рассчитать произведение матриц переноса, перспективной и ортогональной одной из осей.

Матрица переноса:

```
| 1   0   0   0 |
| 0   1   0   0 |
| 0   0   1   0 |
| mx  ly  nz  1 |
```

Перспективная матрица имеет вид:

```
| 1  0  0  p |
| 0  1  0  q |
| 0  0  1  r |
| 0  0  0  1 |
```

Ортогональна матрица оси X имеет вид:

```
| 0  0  0  0 |
| 0  1  0  0 |
| 0  0  1  0 |
| 0  0  0  1 |
```

Результирующая матрица в итоге (при Торт. по X) примет вид:

```
| 0  0   0   p                      |
| 0  1   0   q                      |
| 0  0   1   r                      |
| 0  my  nz  lx*p + my*q + nz*r + 1 |
```

`p=-1/Xc, q=-1/Yc, r=-1/Zc`

Где Xc, Yc, Zc - центры проекций.

Comment: жалко, что так поздно ответили, курсовой я сдала на проверку, но все равно интересно:
где брать эти центры проекций? и куда вставлять координаты трех точек, что мне даны: A(x,y,z), B(x1,y1,z1), C(x2,y2,z2)?

Comment: Я полагаю, что как раз вам могут быть даны "точки схода", т.е. точки в которых сходятся все лучи проекции. Для данного типа преобразований они должны лежать на своих осях (т.е. для X координаты Y и Z будут равны нулю). В таком случае, если мне не изменяет память их тоже можно будет использовать для расчета `p,q,r`, но уже без знака "-".

Имеется два других типа преобразований, например, с использованием матриц поворота вокруг одной из осей, в таком случае точки схода могут находиться в любой части координатной сетки.

Без упора на математику, можно просто подбирать центры проекций.